# Back-End database for image based TableView

Tags: php, mysql, ios, json, uitableview

I am some what a beginner in iOS development, and am beginning to move from the front-end dev to the back-end. I know using JSON with php and MySQL is probably the most common to use for loading table views from databases, but I am wondering if anyone has some insight in where and how to start this process for building a database to load image based user-generated content to TableViews (much like instagram).

I know this is not a programming specific question, just trying to get some direction on where to pin-point my efforts. Appreciate any and all input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so learning how to build a database(MySQL) . I found some links that can help you.

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Database-in-MySQL
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/database-use.html

It isn't advisable to store images in tables because you'll encounter problems when it comes to backing up. Save images in a folder on the server and store their references in the tables.

To Access this images from your app. You'll need to make a post request to your database through an API written in PHP. You can find a good tutorial on how to write a simple PHP API script on google.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation so I wasn't allowed to post more than 2 links. So my answer continues

From your app you hit your API with the necessary parameters you set when writing the PHP script with a POST request. You API should return you the url of the image you seek and you should be able to download the image in your app.

This is a tutorial on how to make a simple NSURL Connection

http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/

Below is another link that might be of good help. Its a simple tutorial that builds a messaging app that hits an API and gets messages from a database. There is a lot of learn from there to fulfill your need.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the traditional ways I find Parse very useful. Parse can manage your whole backend and they have a very powerful free basic plan.

If you focus on images dive here in, to decide wether Parse fits for you or not: https://parse.com/tutorials/saving-images

Comment: Yes, I have looked into Parse a little bit and has seemed like an appropriate consideration. The functionality of the back-end component of the app is to have a few different category based feeds of user-submitted submitted images, where each different category feed is to sort and order images based on the number of views. Hopefully that makes sense and might make a difference on what type of back-end to use...? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you could easily use Parse for this. You can store images in Tables and use querys to sort them. It's also easy to upload them, you only need very few lines of code. Sorry for late response, missed it.